# No UiSlider remove decimal?

Tags: nouislider

How to remove decimals digit from linked output

I am using this code

```
$("#slider_01").noUiSlider({
    start: [2000, 24000],
    connect: true,
    step: 0.01,

    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 28500
    },
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: false,
        thousand: ',',
        prefix: '$ ',
    })
});

$('#slider_01').Link('lower').to($('#value-lower_1'));

$('#slider_01').Link('upper').to($('#value-upper_1'));
```

Comment: What version of nouislider are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decimals `decimals: false` is invalid, use `decimals: 0`. Also, you are setting formatting for the `.val()` method. Use it like this:

```
$('#slider_01').Link('lower').to($('#value-lower_1'), null, wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
    thousand: ',',
    prefix: '$ ',
}));
```

Comment: You'll need to set the formatting for the `Link`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I have remove my liblink, wNumb, jquery.nouislider.min.js, wich was downloaded from your site http://refreshless.com/nouislider, and replace it by your jquery.nouislider.all.min.js wich taken from https://cdn.rawgit.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/458e9fb80706a52d928343d5ba9f3653dcc01e7f/distribute/jquery.nouislider.all.min.js, it start works fine. That was problem, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't have access to the `wNumb` library in the environment I was working with.

Had a look under the hood in the library and this also works:

```
$("#slider_01").noUiSlider({
    ...
    format: {
        to: (v) => parseFloat(v).toFixed(0),
        from: (v) => parseFloat(v).toFixed(0)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's a very old question, but I did not want to include another library Wnumb just to remove the decimal from one place. Here is my solution without using the wnumb.

```
    var slider = document.getElementById('prcsldr');
    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
        start: [10000],
        range: {
            min: 1000,
            max: 50000              
        },
        step: 1000,
        format:{
            to: (v) => v | 0,
            from: (v) => v | 0
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the `step` from `0.01` to `1`.

Comment: look my comment to Lg102 please, there screen.